# Why isn't it possible to change max-height with % in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive menu, with a hamburger icon. I want the menu list to slide in and out, no jquery - pure javascript only.

HTML :

```
<div id="animation">  
</div>
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

CSS :

```
div {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Javascript :

```
var but = document.getElementById('toggle');
var div = document.getElementById('animation');
var animate = function(type, callback){
var inter = -1, start = 100, end = 0;
if(type==true){
    inter = 1;
    start = 0;
    end = 100;
}
var si = setInterval(function(){
    console.log('maxheight');
    div.style.maxHeight = (start + inter) + '%';
    if(start == end){
        clearInterval(si);
    }
}, 10);
}
var hidden = false;
but.onclick = function(){
animate(hidden, function(){
    hidden = (hidden == false) ? true : false;
});
}

div.style.maxHeight = "50%";
```

Comment: have you set the height of the parent container of the div (or the `body` and `html`)?

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) You need to provide more details: What's happening, what do you expect, etc.

Comment: That's because you don't have a parent with a fixed heigth.

Comment: FYI, `if(type==true)` is unnecesary, it's just `if(type)`. Similarly, `hidden = (hidden == false) ? true : false;` is a really long way to write `hidden = !hidden;` Nine times out of ten, if you reach for `==` or `!=` with boolean values, stop and just use the boolean directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a few errors with your code.  I have fixed the js and added comments to what I have changed

```js
var but = document.getElementById('toggle');
var div = document.getElementById('animation');
var animate = function (type, callback) {
  var start = 100,
      end = 0;

  if (type) {
    start = 0;
    end = 100;
  }

  var si = setInterval(function () {
    if (type) { // check whether to open or close animation
      start++;
    } else {
      start--
    }

    div.style.maxHeight = start + '%';

    if (start == end) {
      clearInterval(si);
    }
  }, 10);

  callback.call(this); // do the callback function
}

var hidden = false;
but.onclick = function () {
  animate(hidden, function () {
    hidden = !hidden; // set hidden to opposite
  });
}
```

```css
/*make sure parent container has a height set or max height won't work*/
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} 
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation"></div>
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mrbx6pr/1/)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that proportional `height` in an element needs a fixed height on the parent, and you didn't provided any parent with a fixed `height` because for the `maxHeight` property too *the `%`  Defines the maximum height in % of the parent element*.

You have to put your div in a parent container with a fixed `height`, this is your working code:

```js
var but = document.getElementById('toggle');
var div = document.getElementById('animation');
var animate = function(type, callback) {
  var inter = -1,
    start = 100,
    end = 0;
  if (type) {
    inter = 1;
    start = 0;
    end = 100;
  }
  var si = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('maxheight');
    div.style.maxHeight = (start + inter) + '%';
    if (start == end) {
      clearInterval(si);
    }
  }, 10);
}
var hidden = false;
but.onclick = function() {
  animate(hidden, function() {
    hidden = !hidden ;
  });
}

div.style.maxHeight = "50%";
```

```css
#animation {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="animation">
  </div>
  <button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

**Note:**

As stated in comments there are some statements in your JavaScript code that need to be adjusted:

> `if(type==true)` can be written as  `if(type)`.
>
> `hidden = (hidden == false) ? true : false;` can be shortened to `hidden = !hidden`

Comment: Those JavaScript statements do not _need_ to be fixed, they are perfectly valid, only explicitly stated. Or _is_ there need for shortening? (interpreter performance‽)

Comment: They don't need to be fixed but they can be adjusted, shortening isn't really a question of performance but the code readability, but this shortened line will surely be interpreted faster than the initial one.

Comment: While what you wrote is true about wrapping the div with a parent having a fixed height, div.style.maxHeight = "50%" still does not work.

Comment: @Grimbode no it does, this statement is executed on load because it's outside the click event handler, if you right-click the div and inspect it in console you will find `max-height : 50%`.